# Find all anonymous classes throughout my project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, anonymous-class, structural-search

Is there a way for IntelliJ to locate all the places in my code that define an anonymous class?

I am asking just about *finding*, not changing. I am not asking about converting to lambdas, lambdas are irrelevant here.

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/11/navigate-to-anonymous-classes-with-intellij-idea-11-eap-build-110291/ may be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep. You can use the [Structural Search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html) feature.

`Edit -> Find -> Search Structurally…`

There is already a default template for "Anonymous Classes".

- Click `Existing Templates`
- Under `Java -> Class-based` choose `anonymous classes`
- Click `OK`
- Tweak the search options (if you need) and click `Find`

[image]

[image]